# Definition of $\log^- $ function

Tags: fourier-analysis, logarithms

Can anyone tell me the definition of the $\log^- $ function ? Or give reference where I can also find its properties? I know the analogous $\log^+$ function which is defined as $\log^+ x= \log x$ if $x\geq 1$ and $0 $ if $0\leq x<1.$

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please edit the question to show us a particular example or context where you found it. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a more or less standard notation. For a function $f\colon D\to\Bbb R$
$$
f^+(x)=\max(f(x),0),\quad f^-(x)=\min(f(x),0).
$$
$f^+$ and $f^-$ are known as the positive and negative part of $f$.

Then
$$
\log^-x=\begin{cases}\log x & \text{if }0<x\le1,\\0 & \text{if }x>1.\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Is it also true that $-log^-(x)= log^-{x^{-1}}?$

Comment: No. $\log^-(x^{-1})=-\log^+x$.